# submit_tag with javascript function

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails.I want to call a javascript function when click the submit button.I used submit_tag , but the function did not get triggered.I want some thing like the following ,

```
     <%= submit_tag , :onsubmit => "return validateform()" %>
```

I googled the problem but I couldn't find a solution.Please any one give a solution.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

try onclick

```
<%= submit_tag , :onclick => "return validateform();" %>
```

or if you want to use onsubmit you can use that in your form_tag.

Comment: How can we pass variable ruby variable as parameter to validateform() ?

Comment: try this :onclick => "return validateform(#{@variable});"

Answer (score 7):

You can use something like this on the form tag

```
 <% form_for :bla, :html => { :onsubmit => 'blahblah;' } do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try

```
<%= submit_tag , :onclick => "return validateform()" %>
```

OR

You can Use [button_to_function](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#M002233)

```
<%= button_to_function "Greeting", "validateform()" %>
```

And in your Javascript function, if all the validations pass, submit the form.

Answer (score 3):

You would do it in the form_tag...

`<%= form_tag({:action => :whatever}, {:onSubmit => 'return validateform();'} ) %>`