# Ruby on Rails: Create confirmation view before creating the object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the below code for creating a product:

```
def create
    @customer = Customer.find(params[:customer_id])
    @product = @customer.products.build(params[:product])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to customer_products_path(@customer), notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: customer_products_path.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

To generate the form I use:

```
<%= form_for([@customer, @product]) do |f| %>
```

Now, I am wondering, how can I transfer the use to a separate confirmation page before saving the data to the DB. Also with an edit link, so if needed the user can make changes and submit the records finally.

I looked at other questions on stackoverflow, but was unable to create what I want. Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: I think it's better to resort to a client side confirmation dialog using javascript client side libraries.

Comment: I am not very good with JS. Can you point to some reference guide or other similar pointers?

Comment: JQuery UI confirmation dialog is just an option from a large pool of options.

Comment: you can use [multi step form](http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do client-side confirmation, you need to use JavaScript to listen on the 'form submit' event. You then use jQuery html() to show a lightbox that asks to proceed or not.  It would be related to [using onsubmit event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510260/submit-tag-with-javascript-function) and [rendering a confirmation box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313586/confirm-form-submission-using-bootbox-confirm). Another way with data attributes is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421072/jquery-ui-dialog-instead-of-alert-for-rails-3-data-confirm-attribute)

If you want a database tracking for confirmation (server-side), you can render your model in the 'show' action, but with a different set of buttons.

In your show view, you would then do:

```
<% if @product.confirmed? %>
    ... # normal path to actions for show (edit, delete, back )
<% else %>
    <%= link_to "Confirm', confirm_product_customer_path(@product, @customer) %>
<% end %>
```

However, having an attribute for confirmation in the database, sometimes is a bit of overkill. As Jani suggests in the comments, a client-side confirmation is for most cases good enough.

Comment: If its going to the `show` method the record is getting created. What if the user doesnt want to proceed after the confirmation page is rendered?:)

Comment: Right, with this, you 'create' the model, and then 'confirm' the model. It's is sometimes necessary when a user makes a transaction. If you don't want to write to the database, you need client-side confirmation, e.g. with a lightbox.

Comment: Ok, I added some links on client-side rendering. Is this answer better?

Comment: Yes. Although i am gonna tweak it fit my needs. Get the idea though. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a new button with a parameter:

```
  <%= f.submit %>
  <%= f.submit "Preview", :name => 'preview' %>
```

and in your controller, in create action:

```
if params[:preview]
@product = Product.new(params[:product])
render 'products/previw'
else
# save your object
end
```

and create a new partial for preview.

Comment: What exactly goes inside `# do your stuff`.?

Comment: - I create a new preview view 'products/preview.html.erb'
- How I would save all date on preview view to my DB as a confirmation step?