# Can one Rails button post to create and execute javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms, button

I have a rails form with a submit button, but I'm wondering if it's possible to make this submit button 1) Post to controller create action and also 2) Execute Javascript

Here are the two buttons I essentially want to combine:

```
1. <%= f.submit "Go!", class: "btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block" %>

2. <a href="javascript:ExtInstall()" class="btn btn-default btn-large btn-block" role="button">Download our Google Chrome extension</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your button is part of a form, you can keep its functionality the same as it is now. If it's stand-alone, you'll be best using [`button_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) like so:

```
<%= button_to "Download", post_path, id: "button" %> # -> uses POST http verb, so will send to create action
```

What you're asking is best answered with [`unobtrusive javascript`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript). This will bind your button's `click` event to a function of your choice, allowing you to not only submit the required data, but handle the other functionality you need too:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$("#button").on("click", function(){
    ExtInstall(); //do you have any references for this function?
});
```

Comment: Hmmm... doesn't work for me. I used a console.log and ExtInstall is just not being called, same as when I tried DevDude's suggestion above

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do this by adding an onClick handler in JS to the submit button.

You can see [submit_tag with javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510260/submit-tag-with-javascript-function) for the different ways you can do this.

Comment: hmm can't get it to work, i've tried: `<%= f.submit "Go!", onclick: "javascript:ExtInstall(), class: "btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block" %>` and then all that happens when I click is I get a popup saying `javascript:ExtInstall()` rather than the function executing. Have also tried just `onclick: "ExtInstall()"` in which case the form runs but the installation doesn't trigger. Also tried using `confirm` instead of `onclick`

Comment: `onclick: "ExtInstall()"` should work. Try debugging with alert() or console.log to see if ExtInstall() is being called. BTW, the better option is to use jQuery based onclick event handler as discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070760/javascript-function-in-href-vs-onclick

Comment: It doesn't and console.log shows that it's not being called, but I'm not sure why...